# как получить order id заказа woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть конструкция для получения информации о заказе, при указании id заказа вручную, все работает. Как получить id заказа не зная его? или получить информацию о заказе без id.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'get_order_details_woo',  1, 1  );



function get_order_details_woo ($id, $order )
{
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    $item_data = $order->get_data();



// Iterating through each WC_Order_Item_Product objects
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values) {

        ## Using WC_Order_Item methods ##
        // Item ID is directly accessible from the $item_key in the foreach loop or
        $item_id = $item_values->get_id();

        ## Using WC_Order_Item_Product methods ##

        $item_name = $item_values->get_name(); // Name of the product
        ## Access Order Items data properties (in an array of values) ##
        $item_data = $item_values->get_data();

        $product_name = $item_data['name'];
        $product_id = $item_data['product_id'];
        $variation_id = $item_data['variation_id'];
        $quantity = $item_data['quantity'];
        $tax_class = $item_data['tax_class'];
        $line_subtotal = $item_data['subtotal'];
        $line_subtotal_tax = $item_data['subtotal_tax'];
        $line_total = $item_data['total'];
        $line_total_tax = $item_data['total_tax'];


      //  prepare_arr_items($product_name, $quantity, $line_total, $order_id);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstname = $order->get_billing_first_name();
```

Вот таким методом всё можно передавать.